# why build-essential failed?

Tags: apt, 14.04, xubuntu, software-installation, dependencies

I cannot found solution for this problem:

```
constantia@constantia:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

constantia@constantia:~$ sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.17.5ubuntu5) but 1.17.5ubuntu5.2 is to be installed
            Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: fakeroot but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libalgorithm-merge-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

constantia@constantia:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Sorry, if my questions is so stupid. Maybe somebody explain me from where my problem is? I don't touch the system at all (new installation of 14.04). Thank you.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f libdpkg-perl`??

Comment: what is `apt-cache madison libdpkg-perl`?

Comment: @123456: `madison`?

Comment: It looks like the original program may be dependent on an older version. (Current version of `dpkg-dev` [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dpkg-dev)) Some of your other programs will depend on newer versions of software to function. Basically the developer of the program should have compatibility, or you can install older packages alongside new ones **This is not normally recommended**, but it can be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get install libdpkg-perl=1.17.5ubuntu5` to downgrade `libdpkg-perl`.

You somehow installed a newer version of the package than what is in the repositories, which is causing problems with other packages.

Comment: Thank you very much! But it cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Was there any output?

Comment: No! It's perfect solution if you don't know linux well. It helps me. But it cannot solve my MAIN problem - http://askubuntu.com/q/485642/294465 Thank you very-very much!

Answer (score 4):

Try
Code:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your package list.

Then
Code:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to clean up any partial packages.

Then
Code:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to clean up the apt cache.

Then
Code:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will clean up any unneeded dependencies.

If while doing this you can identify the broken package this code will very forcefully remove it.

Code:

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq <package name>
```

Change package name to the real name of course.

Then, go back to your build-essential install

Code:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

See, if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I re-installed

```
libdpkg-perl
```

and it worked. You can allow synaptic to downgrade this package if you use  synaptic